# How can I find out if there are any objects of a class (memory) being referenced or not in j2me?

Tags: java-me

I am working on a custom text field for a touch device and this text field is to be used in games. This custom text field is a class and has a variable in which the keypad image is stored which is static variable, if I have to display 2 text field in one page(screen) I’ll have to create 2 objects of the text field class and since the keypad image is stored in a static variable it would be shared by both the objects, now I want to know, if any objects are created of the custom keypad class, are these objects(memory) being referenced by any variable, if not I want to free the image memory and reload it when a new object is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), you could keep a static `WeakReference` to the image in your class, and have a non-static (strong) reference in instances of your class:

```
public class CustomTextField {
    // Only necessary if multiple threads can create UI elements
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    private static WeakReference<Image> keypadRef;

    private final Image keypad;

    public CustomTextField() {
        this.keypad = loadKeypad();
    }

    private static Image loadKeypad() {
        Image keypad = null;
        // Same comment as above: you don't need the lock if the UI elements are
        // not created in multiple threads.
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (keypadRef != null) {
                keypad = keypadRef.get();
            }
            // Either there was no existing reference, or it referenced a GCed
            // object.
            if (keypad == null) {
                keypad = new Image();
                keypadRef = new WeakReference(keypad);
            }
        }
        return keypad;
    }
}
```

That makes the keypad image eligible to garbage collection as soon as there are no instances referencing it, otherwise it's kept around and shared between instances.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but there is only one problem, in j2me there is no access to WeakRefrence, nevertheless I could you use the above mentioned code in my other java projects, so once again thanks

Comment: It depends on the J2ME profile, cf. my WeakReference link which is in the J2ME javadoc, not J2SE. You may not have it in the profile you're using (hence my "if"), but some do.

Comment: Hi Frank, well I found out that WeakReference is in the profile I am using, I have a doubt what if I keep the (keypad) variable as non-final, would the results be the same. Coz I am getting an error at compile time at this line (this.keypad = keypad;) saying "The final field keypad cannot be assigned".

Comment: I guess you're not assigning it in the constructor, then. The results are the same whether the field is final or not, I just set it that way as it's better to have fields final if possible (it helps towards immutability, which reduces concurrency problems in a multithreaded environment). But if you're assigning keypad somewhere else than the constructor, do remove the final keyword.

Comment: Thanks Frank assigning it inside the constructor works; previously I assigned it in a function called loadKeypad which was called in the constructor. Thanx a lot, u gave me my birthday gift.

Comment: Happy birthday then. I edited the code to reflect the fact that you can create the keypad in another method, to avoid a large constructor body (I suppose it contains other bits as well) and separate the responsibilities. Don't forget to accept the answer if it fits the requirements.

Comment: @StephenSolomon check CLDC version of your target device. If it's 1.0 (JSR 30), forget about `WeakReference`, if it's 1.1 (JSR 139) then `WeakReference` should work exactly as Frank descrives

Answer (score 1):

IMO for a Java ME app you should have enough understanding of the codebase to know for yourself when memory-hungry objects like images can be freed.

Comment: Thanks for replying, U see this class would be used by other programmers and I can provide a function to free up the resources when the programmer wants too, but then I would be dependent on the programmer to free the resource.